# can not render ' / ' in url in Django templates

Tags: django

> **Update :: Problem solved.just follow the guy below.**

in my urls.py

```
path('', store_view, name='store'),
path('category/<str:category_name>/', category_view, name='category'),
```

in views.py

```
def store_view(request):

  categories = list(Category.objects.all())
  
  context = {     
    'categories': categories,
  }
  return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)


def category_view(request, category_name):

  category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
  
  context = {
      'category': category,
  }
  return render(request, 'store/single-category-view.html', context)
```

in my template : store.html , that is rendered by store_view >>

```
      {% for item in categories %}
        <a href="{% url 'category' item.name %}">
          {{item.name}}
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
```

Now,the problem is, in the category column in my DB, i have got one category called **'Laptop/MacBook'**.when ever this name is passed to the **url**, it says >>

> **"Reverse for 'category' with arguments '('Laptop/MacBook',)' not**
> **found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<category_name>[^/]+)/$']**

But when i changed the category name from **Laptop/MacBook** to **Laptop and MacBook** , it worked fine and showed no error.

But i want to keep it as it was,**'Laptop/MacBook'**.How can i do that??and how do you guys deal with that?

Comment: Why not encode and decode (as in url encode) between store_view and category_view? This will safely transfer your slash to and fro, without breaking the URL.

Comment: I dont know how to do that!!can u help me with the process??I am very new to django.

Comment: Sure checkout my answer. I guess you use Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try encoding and decoding your DB values. Assuming its Python 3:

```
from urllib.parse import quote, unquote

encoded = quote("Laptop/Macbook", safe="")
decoded = unquote(encoded)

print(encoded, decoded)
```

Output:

```
Laptop%2FMacbook Laptop/Macbook
```

With this your route should take in the right param.

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse, request
from django.shortcuts import render

def store_view(request):
    name = "Laptop/Macbook"
    return render(request, './store.html', context={"name": name})

def category_view(request, category_name):
    print(category_name)
    return HttpResponse(b"Here we go!")
```

templatetags/tags.py

```py
from urllib.parse import quote, unquote
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='encode')
def encode(name):
    return quote(name, safe="")

@register.filter(name='decode')
def decode(name):
    return unquote(name)
```

Template:

```
{% load tags %}
<a href="{% url 'category' name|encode %}">
  {{name}}
</a>
```

Don't forget to add in settings:

```
'OPTIONS': {
            'libraries':{
                'tags': 'templatetags.tags',
            }
        },
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219313/discussion-on-answer-by-abhilash-can-not-render-in-url-in-django-templates).

Answer (score 2):

When using a "/", django thinks that you are passing more than one parameter. To fix this, replace `str` by `path` in your urls like so:

```py
path('', store_view, name='store'),
path('category/<path:category_name>/', category_view, name='category'),
```

This will make django understand that the / does not mean there are two separate parameters in your url.